# Using py4j to send matrices to from Python to Java as int[][] arrays

Tags: py4j

I've been using py4j to build a user-friendly Python library around a less user-friendly Java library. For the most part, this has been a breeze, and py4j has been a great tool. However, I've come across a snag when sending matrices between Python and Java.

Specifically, I have a static function in java that accepts, as its arguments, an integer matrix:

```
public class MyClass {
   // ...
   public static MyObject create(int[][] matrix) {
      // ...
   }
}
```

I'd like to be able to call this from Py4j like so:

```
def create_java_object(numpy_matrix):
   # <code here checks that numpy_matrix is a (3 x n) integer matrix>
   # ...
   return java_instance.jvm.my.namespace.MyClass.create(numpy_matrix)
```

This doesn't work, which isn't too surprising, nor does it work if the `numpy_matrix` is instead converted to a list of plain python lists. I had expected that the solution would be to construct a java array and transfer the data over prior to the function call:

```
def create_java_object(numpy_matrix):
   # <code here checks that numpy_matrix is a (3 x n) integer matrix>
   # ...
   java_matrix = java_instance.new_array(java_instance.jvm.int, 3, n)
   for i in range(numpy_matrix.shape[1]):
      java_matrix[0][i] = int(numpy_matrix[0, i])
      java_matrix[1][i] = int(numpy_matrix[1, i])
      java_matrix[2][i] = int(numpy_matrix[2, i])
   return java_instance.jvm.my.namespace.MyClass.create(java_matrix)
```

Now, this code runs correctly. However, it requires approximately **two minutes** to run. The matrices I'm working with, by the way, are on the order of (3 x ~300,000) elements.

Is there a canonical way to do this in Py4j that doesn't require incredible amounts of time just to convert a matrix? I don't mind it taking a second or two, but this is far too slow. If Py4j isn't setup for this kind of communication, is there a Java interop library for Python that is?

**Note**: The Java library treats the `int[][]` matrix as an immutable array; i.e., it never attempts to modify it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution for this particular case that works; though it is not terribly elegant:

Py4j supports efficiently passing a Python `bytearray` object to Java as a `byte[]` array. I worked around the problem by modifying the original library and my Python code.

The new Java code:

```
public class MyClass {
   // ...
   public static MyObject create(int[][] matrix) {
      // ...
   }
   public static MyObject createFromPy4j(byte[] data) {
      java.nio.ByteBuffer buf = java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
      int n = buf.getInt(), m = buf.getInt();
      int[][] matrix = new int[n][m];
      for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
         for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
            matrix[i][j] = buf.getInt();
      return MyClass.create(matrix);
   }
}
```

The new Python code:

```
def create_java_object(numpy_matrix):
   header = array.array('i', list(numpy_matrix.shape))
   body = array.array('i', numpy_matrix.flatten().tolist());
   if sys.byteorder != 'big':
      header.byteswap()
      body.byteswap()
   buf = bytearray(header.tostring() + body.tostring())
   return java_instance.jvm.my.namespace.MyClass.createFromPy4j(buf)
```

This runs in a few seconds rather than a few minutes.

Comment: This would only work for 2D matrices? How about storing the shape length as the first value so that you can send a matrix of any shape?